# access property of a function which is in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, properties

i have a function in which i have to access property . function is in foreach loop and it looks something like this

```
function sectionDetails(sectionData){
  var sectionDetails = [];

  if (sectionData.length > 0) {
    sectionData.forEach(function(item) {
       sectionDetails.push({
           sectionId:item.sectionId,
           sectionName:item.sectionName,
           sectionLayout:item.sectionLayout
       });
    });

    return sectionDetails;
  } else {
    return "Error";
  }
}
```

and i am fetching property values for condition checking,

```
if ($scope.entity[0].sections[0].sectionId === 1 &&
    $scope.entity[0].sections[0].sectionLayout == "linear_layout_vertical") {
  if (dynamicFormObject.formLayout == "linear_layout_horizontal") {
    console.log("sadasd");
    var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
    console.log(newdiv);
    newdiv.setAttribute('horizontal', '');
    newdiv.setAttribute('layout', '');
    newdiv.className('col-md-12');
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
  }
  else if (fieldLayout == "linear_layout_horizontal" && fieldControl === 2) {
    for(var i=1; i<=2; i++) {
      var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
      newdiv.setAttribute('horizontal', '');
      newdiv.setAttribute('layout', '');
      newdiv.className('col-md-6');
      document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    }
  }
```

I need to fetch that property value iterating through foreach and compare in if statement.. Please help

Comment: You should not make `sectionDetails` a function and an Array as well. `this.propertyName =` is how you define a Constructor property. The function in your `.foreach(`in here`)` would create a context issue anyways. In those situations you need to assign `var anyName = this;` outside of the closure, then use the var inside the closure for the correct context.

Comment: Your question is very confuse. Please reformulate a be more specific.

Comment: I can't understand your question. Where is *sectionDetails* called? What is "*that property*"?

Comment: @PHPglue—the *sectionDetails* array is entirely within the function, so other than being mildly confusing, there's no real issue with that. The value of *this* is not used, so irrelevant? But maybe you understand the question better than I.

Comment: Let's avoid confusion. Where do you even call `sectionDetails`? You know, like: `sectionDetails(yourArrayMustBeHere)`.

Comment: @PHPglue I will call the function immediately after function closes and i try to return the sectionDetails value there. The thing any how i need to fetch sectionId and sectionLayout outside the function so i can use that value in the if statement.

Comment: Show us the code. Is `sectionDetails` executing in a loop as well?

Comment: i have written code above. sectionData is in foreach loop and sectioDetails is inside that